# How to query and get both parent and qualified child docs in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES v7.3 and I have maintained parent-child relationship in my index, we know that we can use has_child and has_parent queries to return parent and child doc's respectively, I use has_child query and on the basis of child doc's I get the parent doc's.

What I wanted to know if there is a way using which I can run a has_child query to get both parent doc's and along with it the qualified child doc's also??

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-request-body.html#parent-child-inner-hits) parameter (also works for [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/nested.html) data type).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I also explored the same, also found that there is a considerable performance hit when using it so is this the only option?

Comment: @YashTandon I suppose that poor performance is due to parent-child itself (joins are very limited and have poor performance in ES). However, it is often possible to remodel the data and not use parent-child. If you could provide an example of mapping and queries you make, it would be great. In each case something specific can be done to improve the situation.